# Querying a JSON file to get position in array

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to query a JSON file to set the position of an array. For example a snippet of my JSON file is displayed below:

```
  { "result": [{
        "summonerLevel": "0",
        "summonerID": "0",
        "summonerName": "",
        "summonerIcon": "0"
    }, {
        "summonerLevel": "30",
        "summonerID": "76767383",
        "summonerName": "Solminor",
        "summonerIcon": "916"
    }, {
        "summonerLevel": "30",
        "summonerID": "25470907",
        "summonerName": "Dahid",
        "summonerIcon": "959"
    }, {
        "summonerLevel": "30",
        "summonerID": "72118343",
        "summonerName": "Truehaven",
        "summonerIcon": "956"
    }]
}
```

Currently, I have hard coded the position of the array to 1 which returns "Solminor's" level which is "30":

```
dbsummonerLevel = json.result[1].summonerLevel;
```

I have displayed this variable on my html page:

```
document.getElementById("sLevel").innerHTML = dbsummonerLevel;
```

I would like to replace the array position of [1] to return all elements associated with the `"summonerName"` which the user types in.

Eg. the user types in `"Dahid"` and I want the array position to be at [2] or `"Truehaven"` to set the array position to [3]

EDIT: I'd like to add that my JSON data is in a seperate php file and is being updated all the time from a mysql database, i can't store the json file in my javascript i don't think.

Comment: LEGO LEGENDS:D. ok do you want to display your data over js or php?

Comment: I am assigning the data to a variable in JavaScript, then that variable is being displayed in HTML

Comment: besides finding an array position of inputted name, do you want to return all the data(id, level) associated with certain "summonerName" ?

Comment: yeah i would like all the data associated with that summonername so for example, if the user inputs "Dahid" i want to return the level, name, icon and id from that position in the array

Answer (score 0):

something like this to get the data

```js
function getSummonerData(name, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    if (data.result[i].summonerName === name) {
      return data.result[i];
    }
  }
}
var data = {
  "result": [{
    "summonerLevel": "0",
    "summonerID": "0",
    "summonerName": "",
    "summonerIcon": "0"
  }, {
    "summonerLevel": "30",
    "summonerID": "76767383",
    "summonerName": "Solminor",
    "summonerIcon": "916"
  }, {
    "summonerLevel": "30",
    "summonerID": "25470907",
    "summonerName": "Dahid",
    "summonerIcon": "959"
  }, {
    "summonerLevel": "30",
    "summonerID": "72118343",
    "summonerName": "Truehaven",
    "summonerIcon": "956"
  }]
};
console.log(getSummonerData("Truehaven", data));
```

result:

```
  {
    "summonerLevel": "30",
    "summonerID": "72118343",
    "summonerName": "Truehaven",
    "summonerIcon": "956"
  }
```

then u can do what you want with the summoners data

Answer (score 0):

Use .filter, which return are new array that contains only the elements the that function returned true for.

```
var summonersWithName = json.filter(function (summoner){
    summoner.summonerName === NAME_THE_USER_TYPED_IN
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function like

```
function findIndexBy(property, value) {
  return this.findIndex(item => item[property] === value);
}
```

and use it as

```
findIndexBy.call(arr, 'summonerName', 'Dahid');
```

You can add it to the array prototype for ease. But its not recommended as it may conflict if this method name is used by the language.

```
Array.prototype.findIndexBy = function findBy(property, value) {
  return this.findIndex(item => item[property] === value);
}

arr.findIndexBy('summonerName', 'Dahid');
```

If you want the whole object instead of index, replace `findIndex` with just `find`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming 'userdata' is your initial object

function getDataByName(userdata, name){
    if (typeof name !== "string") throw new Error("Wrong name!");

    var userdata = userdata.result, len = userdata.length;
    while (len--) {
        if (userdata[len]['summonerName'] === name) {
            return userdata[len];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var user = getDataByName(userdata, 'Dahid');
console.log(user);
// output: {summonerLevel: "30", summonerID: "25470907", summonerName: "Dahid", summonerIcon: "959"}

document.getElementById("sLevel").innerHTML = user.summonerLevel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i decided to create a JSON query based on the user input. So when the user types in a user ID, that will form a MySql query which will build a JSON file specific to that user ID. Thanks for your help guys i appreciate it.